# Similarity or dissimilarity between two shapes

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to get compare the similarity or dissimilarity between two shapes of image, and I choose to use Correlation to find out,

codes that I did for it:

```
BW1 = im2bw(img1);
```

[image]

```
BW2 = im2bw(img2);
```

[image]

```
result=corr2(BW2,BW1);
```

The result that I get is:
    ans =  -0.0157

And then I try other images, will give me positive numbers like 0.8714.
If the result is negative value, what does the result mean?
And how does the result tell me the similarity between two shapes in the image? 
Please help me, thanks!

Comment: 1) What do you expect it should mean? 2) This is a site for programming questions, not general questions about math/algorithms that don't have to do with implementation in programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think `corr2` makes any sense in your case. What would be `corr2` if you were to dilate the sape by two pixels? I think you should explore different metrics.

You might be interested in [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between the two shapes.
Some googling brought me to [this FEX contribution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26738-hausdorff-distance).